# what is $\sum_{p\leq x}{p \log p}$ is equal to

Tags: asymptotics

This might be a simple question. But Can any one give me an asymptotic bound for $\sum_{p \leq x}{p \log p}$, where $p$ is a prime number

Comment: Well, it's definitely $O(p^2\log(p))$, but there are probably stronger bounds.

Comment: can it be written as $\Pi_{p\leq x}{\log p}^{p}$

Comment: No, it cannot, it can, however, be written as $\log \Pi_{p\leq x}p^{p}$, which is probably what you meant to write?

Comment: It's equivalent to $\log\left( \prod_p p^p \right)$

Comment: @ Isaac, YES, it was a typo from my side